# Modifying an advanced-indexed subset of a NumPy recarray in place

Tags: python, arrays, indexing, numpy

I have a recarray with a couple columns that I use for selecting a subset. Something like

```
>>> x
   array([ ('label1',True,3),
          ('label2',True,2),
          ('label1',False,4)],
         dtype=[('status', '|S16'), ('select', '|b1'), ('somedata', '<i4')])
```

Data is selected from this array using an approach similar to a [previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055131/how-to-modify-a-numpy-recarray-using-its-two-views).

```
condit=(x['status']=='label1')&(x['select']==True)
x_subids=numpy.where(condit)[0]
x_sub=x[x_subids]
```

Then I do some work on the subset and update the original.

```
x[x_subids]=x_sub
```

I understand that `x_sub` is a copy rather than a view due to advanced indexing, and I was wondering if there was an elegant way of avoiding the array copy and just working with the original given the conditions that I need to subset the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The kind of modifications you mention in the comments to my first answer can be done with the [`numpy.place()` function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.place.html):

```
>>> import numpy
>>> x = numpy.array([("label1",True,3), ("label2",False,2), ("label1",True,4)],
...     dtype=[("status", "|S16"), ("select", "|b1"), ("somedata", ">> mask = x["select"]
>>> numpy.place(x["somedata"], mask, (5, 6))
>>> print x
[('label1', True, 5) ('label2', False, 2) ('label1', True, 6)]
>>> numpy.place(x["status"], mask, "label3")
>>> print x
[('label3', True, 5) ('label2', False, 2) ('label3', True, 6)]
```

Note that

1. I changed the values and conditions a bit for the sake of a pertinent example.
2. This time, the values where `mask` is `True` are selected again, not masked out as in my previous answer.
3. The `==True` part in your mask `condit` is redundant, just leave it out :)

Comment: This works very well and is more elegant than what I was doing earlier.

Comment: This is a good general solution for applying ufuncs to boolean-selected parts of an array, since masks don't seem to work.  I needed to `np.clip` only a set of the array, but even using `np.ma.clip` on a masked array will still clip the masked values.  `np.place` it is.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a "masked array":

```
masked = numpy.ma.array(x, 
                        mask=(x['status']!='label1')|(x['select']!=True),
                        copy=False)
```

Note that the mask is the inverse of your `condit`, since the values where the mask is `True` are masked out.  You can now apply any numpy ufunc to this masked array, and only the values not masked out are affected.

Comment: This looks interesting. I haven't used masked arrays before. I will try this and report back.

Comment: If this approach works fine actually depends on what modifications you are performing.  You just said "some work" :)

Comment: The main "work" done are statements like `x_sub['select']=False` or `x_sub['somedata']=y` where `y` is another array where `len(y)=x_sub.shape[0]`.

Comment: Hmm, let's say `x_mask=` what you wrote in your answer, would I be able to do the operations of the type I mentioned in my last comment? I'm clearly new to masked arrays.

Comment: I would have expected this kind of modifications to work, but it seems they don't.  I try to give an additional answer based on this additional information :)